# Signature does not match s3 GET object

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an image in the amazon s3 which has ACL of autherized-users. I'm trying to retrieve that image with GET method. The javascript method (in angular js) looks like this
(In the following example, response contains the necessary data such as authHeader)

```
                var uri = 'https://sample.s3.amazonaws.com/sample/image.jpg';
                var postParams = response.data;

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.addEventListener("load", downloadComplete, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("error", downloadFailed, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("abort", downloadCanceled, false);

                function downloadComplete(e) {

                    var xhr = e.srcElement || e.target;
                    if(xhr.status === 200) { //success status
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                }
                function downloadFailed(e) {
                    debugger;
                }
                function downloadCanceled(e) {
                    debugger;
                }

                xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', postParams.authHeader);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-content-sha256', postParams.payloadHash);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Host', "sample.s3.amazonaws.com");
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-date', postParams.date);
                xhr.send();
```

But I get a 403 exception which says SignatureDoesNotMatch. Is there anything i'm doing wrong? I'm quite sure that the values i'm providing are correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you send `x-amz-content-sha256` with a `GET` request?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot :  because if I dont, I get this following error message                                                                                 `<Code>UnsignedContentSHA256NotAllowed</Code><Message>The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header
 must be a valid SHA256.</Message>`

Comment: Ah, okay, because you're using the authorization header instead of query string authentication.  The value would be the sha256 of an empty string `e3b0...b855`. Makes sense.